# How can I re-assign values in a one-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment, indexoutofboundsexception

My question is two-fold.

I have an array:

```
double [] temperature = {60.9, 62.6, 67.4, 71.5, 77.1, 81.2, 82.4, 82.5, 81.1, 75.3, 68.8, 63.0};
```

When I try to convert these Fahrenheit values to Celsius or Kelvin using:

```
for(int index = 0; index <= temperature.length; index++) {
    temperature[index] = temperature[index] * tempConverter;
    averageTemp += temperature[index];
}
```

I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on `temperature[index = temperature[index] * tempConverter;`

1. Why do I get this error?
2. How do I fix this and reassign my values?

Comment: In the `for`-loop condition it must be `index < temperature.length`. Otherwise the loop is executed with `index = temperature.length` which is out of bounds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of length **n** which starts on index **0** will have its last index at **n-1**.

At the moment your loop will go from **0** to **n** inclusive (`<= n`), which will make it out of bounds from the reserved space when it reaches index **n**. Instead you need to go from **0** to **n** *exclusive* (`< n`), like this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++) {
    ...
}
```

Think of the array of length 3 with the elements representing their own indexes:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
```

Trying to access the element at index = array length (3) will not work because there is no element at index 3 in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to use `<` instead of `<=`:

```
for(int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++)
```

Consider an array with one element. That would make `array.length` equal to `1`, and if you used `<=` you would inspect both `array[0]` and `array[1]`... but you know there's only one element. That's why you use `<` instead.